# Can't grab the Wrench on the wall in Crash Landing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-crash-landing

The game loads, I can read the quest book. I try to grab the wrench off the wall and it won't come off. I just keep pounding the wall with my hands. The game is single player hardcore, no networking or servers, so it's probably not a spawn protection thing.

Any thoughts on how I can complete the first quest without the wrench?

Answer (score 2):

The wrench is contained in an drying rack. The rack looks like a beam of wood on which the wrench rests. You have to right-click the actual wooden beam thats above the wrench to acquire the wrench.

Comment: It's not an item frame, it's a Tinker's Construct drying rack.